# Exporting and Importing and with Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I've created an App that uses Core Datam storing values of some entities on it.
I want to export core data values so that than I can import it again in other devices.
After storing the data I'd like to send email with it or sync it into iCloud.
Can you let me know what's the best file format to do that (csv, xml, json,pdf,...)?
I know a few years ago perhaps xml would be nice. But what about now with swift 3?

Comment: I'd recommend either XML / Plist or JSON but there is no built-in converter. You have to write it yourself.

Comment: What about with csv, is there a built-in converter?

Comment: No, but CSV is not recommendable anyway. If you have more than one Core Data entity CSV will get confused.

Comment: Oh I see. From those you recommend what do you think it's most efficient and easier? I have 3 entities. Each one has a lot of attributes...

Comment: Actually they are equal, because the source of both is an array / dictionary structure in Swift. The converter must map the Core Data model into a array / dictionary structure.

Comment: Try looking at NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: So, with xml or JSON I can export and Import it again latter? Or send the file with email, or store it in iCloud?

Comment: Yes, both are plain text files.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks a lot

Comment: If anyone has a tutorial (link) please feel free to post it here

Comment: I realize one thing. In my entities in core data I have attributes as Strings,  Double and Images. So is it possible to store every thing (Strings + double + Image)  in any of this files? To import latter